# assign value to pointer char?

Tags: c, struct, strncpy

```
struct group {
    char *name;
    struct user *users;
    struct xct *xcts;
    struct group *next;
};

int add_group(Group **group_list_ptr, const char *group_name) {
printf("%p\n",group_list_ptr);
*group_list_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct group));

printf("%p\n",*group_list_ptr);
printf("%p\n",(*group_list_ptr)->name);
(*group_list_ptr)->name = malloc(sizeof(*group_name));
printf("%p\n",(*group_list_ptr)->name);
strncpy((*group_list_ptr)->(*name), "hello", strlen(*group_name));
//printf("%s\n",(*group_list_ptr)->name);
return 0;
```

}

how can i assign a value to *name. After i allocated memory for the struct, I allocated memory for the name

```
strncpy((*group_list_ptr)->(*name), "hello", strlen(*group_name));
```

I am testing it out with "hello", but i want to copy const char *group_name.

I get errors

```
lists.c:24:32: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
lists.c:24:32: error: too few arguments to function ‘strncpy’
```

Comment: my bad strncpy((*group_list_ptr)->(*name), "hello", sizeof(*group_name));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strncpy((*group_list_ptr)->name, "hello", strlen("hello"));
```

You don't want to dereference the name member, which is the compiler error.

You also can't use sizeof to get the length of a string. Use strlen().

For strcpy() the last parameter is the length of the string you're copying. Be sure it's smaller than the destination buffer!

Comment: Sorry there was a typo
The struct has a char * name;

strncpy((*group_list_ptr)->(*name), "hello", strlen(*group_name));

but the data type in the struct is char * name. 
(*group_list_ptr)->name, so why would this work?

Comment: Ok, but you're still copying "hello" and strlen'ing *group_name. That should be cleaned up too.

Comment: The name parameter in group_list_ptr is a char*, which is what you want to pass to strncpy. That is why (*group_list_ptr)->name works.